# Win10 Pro - Why am I now unable to copy/delete file on a media server (I was previously)

Tags: windows-10, copy, media-server

I'm trying to regain copy/delete access to a DLNA media server I've set up.
After initially creating it I was able to copy files to it & delete them. After about an hour I was prevented from doing so, although I could still play the files already in the server from my Humax PVR across my LAN, so it appears to be setup correctly (Network discovery is on).

I'm designated as Administrator In my Window's account.

Any other details required?

[image]

Comment: Which DLNA media server?

Comment: @harrymc The one built into Win10, that's setup by going to 'Media Streaming Options' within Control Panel->Network & sharing centre and as shown in the image I posted.  Unsure how else to describe it,

Comment: How are you trying to access the files and from where (another computer)? A network share?

Comment: Dragging & dropping them from the PC's File Explorer/Freecommander etc.

Comment: Is it in a network share? Or are you doing it on the same computer that is the media server? (Please be very explicit, because I can't spend so much time on asking questions.)

Comment: Do you have the knowledge to provide a solution to my problem?